# PlantUML - is there an api doc kind of reference anywhere?

Tags: plantuml, c4-model

For programing languages like java/php/.net etc we always have api doc, by going through which we can find out what parameter/argument a method/constructor etc takes.

I don't find anything like that on [plantuml.com](https://plantuml.com/guide). And even the ide's plugins don't give this info.

[image]

[image]

The IDE's(vscode in my case) only show the available components available but not their usage/description/arguments etc.

Where can I look to find the usage of component or otherway put, how can I know how to use plantuml components.